# Wild card search in couchdb

Tags: java, javascript, json, couchdb

Iam new to couchdb.I want to know whether wild card search is possible in couchdb or not.if it is possible give me sample example for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the {} (empty object) is a wild card in couch db. For example:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5984/database/_design/docName/_view/viewName?key={}
```

Will return everything. You can also use {} in startkey and endkey and anywhere else you want a wildcard. It will match all keys.