# Wildcard CouchDB search

Tags: javascript, jquery, couchdb

I am having some trouble with searching using wildcards.

My understanding is that I can use the empty object, `{}`, as a wildcard to return all matches.

I have seen a few other questions about this, and they all seem to say the same thing. Most notably [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24926684/wild-card-search-in-couchdb).

For simplicity sake, I am attempting to use one view as a search for a multitude of possibilities. As you can see in the code below, the only items I am guaranteed to be filled in are `start` and `end`, everything else could be blank. If it is blank, I am trying to use a wildcard to just match anything. This gives me the possibility of searching by `name` and `obj1`, or just `obj4`, or maybe `obj2` and `obj3`, etc..

My search, using the CouchDB jQuery plugin is as such:

```
function getHistory(db, name, start, end, obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4){
  $.couch.db(db).view("path/to/view", {
    //startkey: [name, start, obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4],
    //endkey: [name, end, obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4],
    startkey: [name],
    endkey: [name],
    success: function(data) {
console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(status) {
        console.log(status);
    },
    reduce: false
  });
}
```

The code in comments is what I want to search for. The code not in comments is my attempt to use the wildcard.

For whatever reason, whenever `name` is the `{}`, it returns nothing. When I say returns, I mean the `data.rows` is empty.

When the name is a an actual name, it returns the found rows correctly, so I know the view works.

Here is the view: (`deleted` and `doc` are fields in the document)

```
function(docu){
  if(!docu.deleted){
    if(docu.doc == "DOCTYPEHERE"){
      emit([docu.name], docu);
    }
  }
}
```

My questions are this:

- Why isn't this wildcard working for me when both `startkey` and `endkey` are `{}`?
- Am I missing some underlying knowledge of using wildcards?

Comment: There is no such thing as wildcards in CouchDB views. The usage of `{}` is as a "high value", typically as part of the `end_key`, so you can find all values, even when they are not typical ASCII characters (such as special characters and Unicode) I would highly recommend checking out the official [Guide to Views](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/couchapp/views/intro.html) since you are getting started.

Comment: @DominicBarnes Thank you for the explanation, I understand a little better now. I have solved my problem, and instead of attempting to search for multiple keys that may or may not be filled in, I searched the `start` and `end` and then filtered based on the other keys.

Comment: The "wildcard" would be a  startkey=null and an endkey={}. Therefore, it's preferred to use \ufff0 instead of {} since it's a higher character.